# Dynamic help for dropdown lists

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a multiple selects and I need to have some kind of help for each item in each select. I have generated an array with values for each select and now I need to select choose right array for each select. Example bellow:

```
ArrayA[1] = "text";
ArrayA[2] = "text2";

ArrayB[1] = "text";
ArrayB[2] = "text2";

<select id="select1" class="DDL ArrayA">...</select><span class="help">
<select id="select2" class="DDL ArrayB">...</select><span class="help">
```

I need to put text from the array which is named as class in the select box to the span with class "help". How can I do this?

This is what I have right now:

```
$(this).parent().children().closest('span').text(ARRAY_NAME[$('option:selected', this).val()]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `eval()` function to parse the relevant array name from the corresponding select:

example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/W3VB2/)

html:

```
<div><select id="SEL1" class="DDL Array">
    <option selected value="-1" disabled="disabled">choose something</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    </select><span class="help"></span></div>
<div><select id="SEL2" class="DDL Array">
    <option selected value="-1" disabled="disabled">choose something</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
</select><span class="help"></span></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var ArraySEL1=[],ArraySEL2=[];
    ArraySEL1[1] = "array 1 text";
    ArraySEL1[2] = "array 1 text2";

    ArraySEL2[1] = "array 2 text";
    ArraySEL2[2] = "array 2 text2";

    $("select").change(function () {
        var id_of_current_select = $(this).attr("id");
        var selected_value = $(this).val();
        var the_help_text = eval("Array"+id_of_current_select+"["+selected_value+"]");
        $(".help",$(this).parent()).html(the_help_text);

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Never heard about eval before :)

Comment: glad i could help :) eval does wonders, it executes javascript from plain text